# Could implanting false memories change someone's perception immediately?

Tags: hard-science, psychology, brain

This question is about how the brain works in that aspect, if it's even known.

I mean with the question that a person might react to something with fear, happiness, disappointment, or whatever other feeling.

These feelings are biological but also are built around the memories about that something.

I'm far from a brain expert, but I think that the brain somehow summarizes all of this memories, in a separate way, to give that feeling immediately.

If that were the case then changing this memories would give scenarios sort of strange for the person, as, for example, it might feel fear about something  with which everything he can recall are good memories or the opposite, with time the brain might become wired to act accordingly to its memories, but it would result in some severe confusion for the person meanwhile.

We can consider that we have a perfect technology for creating the false memories with as much detail as desired, exchanging it for others, but we cannot still change the "summary" that the brain does (if it happens).

According to actual knowledge about the brain, could changing these memories actually immediately change the behavior of a person?

Not very sure if this goes here or in http://cogsci.stackexchange.com, but as implanting these level of false memories is, as far as I know, absolute science fiction, I'm posting here.

I'm writing my comment here to better explain what would be the hard science part:

The [hard-science] part is most about having a separate "zone" for the response that "summarized" memories in form of feelings produce, and the memories themselves, I don't think it's that far fetched that studies have been able to determine that nowadays, the implanting of memories is less important, for that the thing to check would be that someone who were to get the opposite feelings, if both feelings and memories cannot exist in a separate manner, with brains being of equal "functionality", would prove that implanting memories would cause that associated feelings to change.

With the last thing I want to mean that, for example, between twin brothers, if one of them had experiences that made to develop the opposite feeling about something, I think that would prove that, as the brain has the same functionality, it would make that feelings to change. And, in general, a brain, unless there's some abnormality, is not to work too different in any random person in this aspect (in how it would process them, due to its own working, if those were the memories instead of others), I guess.

Even if restricting it to this wouldn't be enough, I'd like to reopen without the hard-science tag.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might want to drop the [tag:hard-science] tag in favour of [tag:science-based]. There could be statistics out there somewhere, but transformation (at least as far as I can tell) will probably be nebulous and less well defined than the tag hopes for.

Comment: @Agrajag,the important part of the question is if the brain makes this distinction between the feelings the memory gives, and the memories itself, I want an answer as much hard science based as possible with that, as for implanting memories that perfectly we can go into suspension of disbelief.

Comment: In that case what you are asking may be too subjective to be answered.

Comment: Please understand that the [tag:hard-science] tag has nothing to do with "hard science fiction."  It's ruthless and has a very strict mandate.  We can't implant false memories other than dubiously through hypnosis, which means there is no hard science (factual proof in the form of "equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, [and] other citations") with which to answer your question.  The tag is an absolute.  It doesn't allow for "as much hard science based as possible."

Comment: You might like to research a real project that tried to do just this, [MkUltra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_MKUltra)

Comment: @user2638180 [hard-science] is for questions where the science already exists and you want to use equations or serious published research in the answers.  Implanting memories is not currently possible and there is no technology for it.  There are no equations and no published papers about it (aside from some soft science about trying to change memories that is quite controversial and problematic and not about brain science at all).  If you persist in wanting [hard-science] I predict your question will be closed (I can't promise changing the tag will save the question though).

Comment: @Cyn, the [hard-science] part is most about having a separate "zone" for the response that "summarized" memories in form of feelings produce, and the memories themselves, I don't think it's that far fetched that studies have been able to determine that nowadays, the implanting of memories is less important, for that the thing to check would be that someone who were to get the opposite feelings, if both feelings and memories cannot exist in a separate manner, with brains being of equal "functionality", would prove that implanting memories would cause that associated feelings to change.

Comment: This question seems to be about the real-world application of memory implanting, but since its a fictional topic you seem to have just put it here. I don't see any indication that this is for worldbuilding, especially with the [hard-science] tag which **requires** answers be back with evidence, equations or papers. If it helps, memory transplants have occurred in mice, but its nothing like what you are mentioning. I would be happy to vote to reopen the question if it didn't require a [hard-science] answer.

Comment: I too would vote to re-open without hard-science.  This strikes me as a question right up WorldBuilding's alley, but you can't have a hard-science question which requires including "implanting memories" unless there is a readily available hard science way to implement memories (which I am quite confident there is not... or at least if I told you how to do it, I'd have to kill you)

Comment: This happens. Did you ever dream that you "remembered" something that actually never happened? I once had a case like that. I remembered a 1970's TV series. I was about to speak about it, but something did not make sense. Suddenly I thought: If I remember it that well, I never recalled I thought about it **earlier**, and that was the clue. I searched the web, and such TV series never existed. So, if faking is not perfect, things may clash and raise your suspicion. So, you may act as if that was real, but the brain may detect an imperfect lie.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes it is possible, but it would be unpredictable".

This has a hard science tag, so this draft might need a few revisions, including references, which I will attend to as time permits. Be aware that the best hard science out there is still very speculative, just marginally better than reading tea leaves

Memories are mediated by the hippocampus and mapped into other areas of the brain.

For a long time, the hippocampus was believed to be the seat of long term memory, because damage or removal of the hippocampus would result in instant and irreversible amnesia. However, by adding the use of functional brain scans to what has been determined through decade of experiment and modelling, we now know there is much more to the story.

Be aware the the best functional brain scan technology only has a 3 mm resolution today (2019). That is pretty coarse for a structure that is only 3 cm³ in volume, so our understanding is still very blurry.

Functional brain scans show a physical mapping process occurring during both memory encoding and reconstruction. The word reconstruction is used deliberately rather than recall because the process of recall is as important as the process of encoding.

```
Sidebar ...be patient and you'll see how his fits.

During execution of spatial tasks, regions of the hippocampus activate in response to 
achieving decision points in the task. For example, if the task is a maze, then at 
each decision point a different set of physical regions of the hippocampus will activate.

What is very interesting is that during execution of non-spatial tasks, like 
solving a math problem, the hippocampus exhibits exactly the same kind of activity.
```

We have known for a long time that the hippocampus is active in long term recall. With the advent of readily available brain scan techniques, we can see that its role in long term recall is active rather than passive, and *essentially identical to its activity in solving spatial problems*.

We also know that the hippocampus is crucial to forming new memories. When new data is first introduced to the brain, the hippocampus is recruited, and *exhibits the same sort of activity that it does in solving spatial problems*.

In effect, the hippocampus is a spatial mapping organ that has been adapted into a general problem solving tool. Think of it as being similar to the GPU in a modern graphics card, specialized for some function, but over time has been adapted to solve a broad range of problems unrelated to its original intent.

For a long time, psychologists have known about the bookend effect. People tend to remember the first time they did something, the last time they did something, but not much in between. This why the first time you drive a route it seems so much longer than subsequent times.

```
Data deduplication
* often called intelligent compression or single-instance storage 
* is a process that eliminates redundant copies of data and reduces storage 
overhead. Data deduplication techniques ensure that only one unique instance of data 
is retained on storage media, such as disk, flash or tape
```

As near as we can tell (at this point its an educated guess backed by experiment and modelling), during memory encoding the hippocampus mediates an aggressive deduplication process. That process compartmentalizes the new memory into fragments representing the state of the brain at that point in time and builds a map of some sort (As a database person I think of it as a key) to tie the fragments back together.

We do not keep detailed memories at all, only statistically reinforced probabilities (described as the sum of the activation functions for the involved neurons - I don't write that kind of math, sorry).

```
This actually introduces the specific technical issues to be resolved 
to "implant" false memories, and also why the results might be unpredictable
no matter how good the tech is.
```

During recall, the hippocampus is recruited to find and reassemble the memory fragments into a comprehensive whole, again treating it as a spatial navigation problem.

This is why human memory is so fallible.

**Examples of this mechanism in action:**

My wife often wears a blue dress to church. We get separated, so when I go looking for her and have trouble finding her because she's wearing a green dress today. The reconstructed memory has been statistically reinforced to blue as part of the deduplication and reconstruction process.

"Oh, I misread that"

The well known phenomenon that no two eyewitnesses of an event recall it exactly the same.

**Memory and Emotion**

From experimental and clinical studies we know that impairment of emotion processing also inhibits memory encoding

It turns out that you can't really separate memory from emotion, because part of the memory encoding process includes a partial state of the amygdala.

From an experiential perspective, I remember what it felt like to really enjoy a good fireworks show. After brain damage impairing emotional processing, (1) I find it difficult to encode new memories and (2) The only "feeling" i get from the same fireworks show is the sensation of the booms rattling my internal organs, kind of like indigestion.

What is interesting (to me) is that recall causes the same areas of the brain to be activated as the original event (with the caveat that the encoding process is lossy) so there is little difference in the state of the brain during recall as opposed to the original event. The fact that I can recall (reconstruct) emotional states that I can no longer experience in the immediate says that there is a different mediator for recalled emotion versus immediate emotion.

---

Links:

- Coding of episodic memory:
  https://www.pnas.org/content/115/5/1093.short
- Spatial processing:
  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002839321730115X
- Spatial processing:
  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304394018303331
- Reconstruction of memory:
  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S136466131830264X
- Hippocampus as spatial processor:
  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/hipo.22750
- Role of emotion in forming memories:
  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352154617301638
- Memory compression:
  https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09658211.2017.1406120
- Memory encoding:
  https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0204685
- Memory Integration Theory: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301008217302174
- Application of hippocampus model in machine learning: http://teaching-machines.cc/nips2017/papers/nips17-teaching_paper-13.pdf

Comment: You actually need the citations, approbations, and links to meet the [tag:hard-science] mandate.  I'll remove my downvote (and likely upvote) if you supply the fair number of citations this answer requires.

Answer (score -1):

80% of memories are eventually forgotten. (As per forgetting Curves which follow Zipfy progressions, also known as the 20/80 rule [Forgetting Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetting_curve) [Zipfs Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law)).

Upon making memories, and reviewing them, we create the neural pathways that guide our actions.([Making Pathways](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms13375/)) Unless an event specifically references a memory, the pathways will largely remain unaffected. (As is evidenced by neural studies showing the pathways in our brains make our decisions before we actively decide: [Decision-making pathways in action](http://exploringthemind.com/the-mind/brain-scans-can-reveal-your-decisions-7-seconds-before-you-decide) )

So as far as implanting false memories, it won't change much. (This is part of why confirmation bias is a problem. I recommend looking up Hysteresis of opinions for further information).

That said, however, there are ways to implant false memories currently, but the methods of doing so also directly impact the person's present, so would not apply to your scenario.[False Memories](https://www.psychologistworld.com/memory/false-memories-questioning-eyewitness-testimony)

Comment: I regularly visit a 96-year-old WWII vet.  He's remembering memories that he hasn't thought about in decades and decades.  I've worked with associates who experienced tremendous childhood trauma that affects their behavior as adults today - but they, themselves, cannot (or will not) remember what caused the trauma.  I want proof that we forget anything, much less 80%.

Comment: There are people, usually traumatised that when aroused experience hyperthymesia, what's the evidence about what they've forgotten.

Comment: @Agrajag I added sources. You may remove your notice now.

Comment: @JBH Sources added.

Comment: Forgetting curves are hypothetical.  Remember that WWII vet I visit?  He, alone, disproves them.  And Zipfs Law has nothing to do with memory.  It's just a means of working through statistics.  But, thanks for adding the links, they do improve your answer.  Also, the notice wasn't added by Agrajag.  It's added by the Mods.

Comment: @Forgetting curves are a general rule, not a specific rule. In other words, it's a general pattern, not an absolute. As such, your vet isn't disproof, just an exception. As one psychologist once told me, "Individually, each person is unique and different. As a whole, they're more predictable than the sun rising."

Comment: @JBH If you want proof we forget stuff, try remembering what you had for dinner on 17 January 2008. The reality is that we forget far more than 99% of stuff that never made it to long term memory. But even long-term memory fails, as can easily be seen by trying to get back into something you used to be great at 20 years ago. Sure, you remember a lot of things, but you forget a lot too. And the longevity of a memory is related not only to age, but how often you access it and how strong it was. I remember dropping a 2x4 on my toe on my third birthday. Very well. No idea what kind of cake it was.

Comment: As for the 80/20 thing, that sounds a lot like BS, even if we restrict it to reasonably strong, long term memories. The brain is finite in capacity, so over time the percentage of forgotten memories will approach 100%. Although I'm not sure that's important to the answer as it applies to the question.

Comment: @MichaelS, that doesn't proven you've forgotten something. It only proves that human memory doens't work well with a chronological index. Speaking with the aged, alzheimer's patients, etc. all demonstrate the capacity to remember. My complaint is that there is no scientific proof for what any statistical group of people can or cannot remember (or, do or do not forget) and the fact that at any given moment you can't remember something (e.g., the cake at your 3rd birthday) isn't proof that you can't remember it, only that the association needed to recall it didn't meet the necessary threshold.

Comment: @MichaelS, I will agree that the mind has a finite capacity (though I'm not qualified to assert what that capacity is).  Note, though, that you can only statistically approach 100% forgetfulness if your life is so long that what you can remember is statistically negligible compared to what you've experienced.  I'm not convinced our 80-100 year average lifespans come anywhere near that level of experience (the WWII vet remembering his youth would discredit the assertion).

Comment: @JBH, Talking to those people, you'll find that they have a very limited ability to recall their youth, and tend to recount the same stories over and over. They also tend to change the details over time, because they really only remember the broad strokes of the stories they remember. What you're asking for is proof of something not existing, when the burden is to prove it does. In practice, it's clear that people simply forget things all the time, but quite impossible to prove the memories are "truly gone".